# Remove the duplicate elements in-place, given a sorted vector with O(1) extra memory

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, duplicates, time-complexity

I am trying to remove the duplicate elements in a sorted vector such that each element appears only once.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void removeDuplicates(vector<int> &nums)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    unsigned int j = 1;

    while(j < nums.size()-1)
    {
        if(nums.at(j) == nums.at(j-1))
        {
            it = nums.begin()+j;
            nums.erase(it);
            --j;            // for every removal, correct the index
        }
        j += 1;             // increment the index
    }
}

int main ()
{
    vector <int> vect;
    int arr[] = {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4}; // the given array
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrSize-1; i++)    // assign values to the vector
    {
        vect.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    removeDuplicates(vect);

    cout << "The unique vector elements are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vect[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, the output is

```
 The vector unique elements are: 0 1 2 3 4
```

The question gives the following instruction:

> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

In my code, the Big O time complexity is O(n).

- How can I remove the duplicates in-place with an extra memory of O(1)?

Comment: You are looking for [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). Even if you are not allowed to use it, you could study how it's implemented.

Comment: O(n) time complexity would be fine, what is asked for is O(1) extra space; at the moment your time complexity is actually more like O(n²), as every `erase` costs on average O(n), and your space complexity is O(n) for the extra vector.

Comment: The question doesn't ask you to have O(1) time complexity.

Comment: `nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums.end());` is what you want.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is exactly what I was looking for. Note, you forgot one bracket. It should be `nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()), nums.end());`. If you can write that as an answer I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get rid of duplicates is to use what's already available in the standard library:

```
nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()), nums.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can remove the duplicates in-place with a time complexity of O(1)?

You can't. Even with the vector sorted, you simply must compare every single element to know whether it is unique or not. O(N) is optimal.

However, O(1) time complexity wasn't required by the task either:

> ... with **O(1) extra memory**.

There was no mention of time complexity constraint - only space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in place (no extra memory) with a complexity O(n) by simply using two indices, one for reading the elements and one for writing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void removeDuplicates(std::vector<int> &nums)
{
    unsigned int j = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if(nums.at(i) != nums.at(i-1))
        {
            nums.at(j++) = nums.at(i);
        }
    }
    nums.resize(j);
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector <int> vect;
    int arr[] = {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4}; // the given array
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrSize-1; i++)    // assign values to the vector
    {
        vect.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    removeDuplicates(vect);

    std::cout << "The unique vector elements are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vect[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```